# Cloudinary OpenUpload widget is not opening in my js

Tags: javascript, html, cloudinary

I am trying to upload my photos in cloudinary. So, I have a cloud name and upload_preset too. So I integrated the javascript given in the cloudinary website inside my html file. Onclick of the hyperlink, the widget should open. But it is not opening.

Please find my html file below. If I miss out any parameters for the unsigned upload, Please let me know.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload multiple images</a>

        <script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

        <script type="text/javascript">  
          document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
            cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'mycloudname', sources: [ 'local', 'url', 'camera', 'image_search', 
                         'facebook', 'dropbox', 'google_photos' ], upload_preset: 'myuploadpreset'}, 
              function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
          }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an unsigned upload, the script's source needs the http in it.

```
 src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"
```

has to be replaced with the following.

```
src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine and working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload multiple images</a>

        <script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

        <script type="text/javascript">  
          document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
            cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'mycloudname', sources: [ 'local', 'url', 'camera', 'image_search', 
                         'facebook', 'dropbox', 'google_photos' ], upload_preset: 'myuploadpreset'}, 
              function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
          }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jsbin example - https://jsbin.com/meyuwiyicu/edit?html,output

Maybe share the error log from the console?

Comment: It looks like a protocol-relative URL problem (https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). It's hard to say why, but It’s always safe to request HTTPS assets directly. https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js

Comment: Working now for me